Creating virtual environment using conda
I'm new at using anaconda, I'm sorry if this a stupid question. I'm trying to create virtual environment using conda. When I input this:
conda create -name tf_env python=3.11
I get the following output:
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - tf_env

Current channels:

  - defaults

How do I fix this? I have tried conda update --all but it didn't work.


What "didn't work" when you ran the conda update command? Can you edit the post to include the error message you were given?

maybe you typoed above, but if not, try with two dashes before name
conda create --name tf_env python=3.11

